# An admin for model "CustomUser" has to be registered to be referenced by FolderAdmin.autocomplete_fields

Tags: django, django-admin, django-filer

I am trying to install `django-filer` and after following the installation docs(pip install, add to `INSTALLED_APPS` etc), when I try run my dev server I get the following error in the terminal...

```
ERRORS:
<class 'filer.admin.folderadmin.FolderAdmin'>: (admin.E039) An admin for model "CustomUser" has to be registered to be referenced by FolderAdmin.autocomplete_fields.
<class 'filer.admin.permissionadmin.PermissionAdmin'>: (admin.E039) An admin for model "CustomUser" has to be registered to be referenced by PermissionAdmin.autocomplete_fields.
```

As visible in the error output. I've extended the Django user model with `CustomUser`. I have also extended `AdminSite` to get custom urls in the admin. So perhaps extending these is causing the error. Any possible solution to this?

The error says `an admin has to be registered` and I do have multiple superusers registered.